# Echo Internation language retrieved from MySQL Db

Tags: php, mysql, internationalization

I have setup my DB collation to `utf8_unicode_ci` but when echo the results of db it prints out `???` or differents charachters for different internation languages, any idea what is wrong?

My html header is `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">`

Comment: you have to set up client encoding also. and it depends on the DB driver you are using which you forgot to mention of course. for the plain mysql driver it's `mysql_set_charset('utf8');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Shrapnel commented, solution is `mysql_set_charset('utf8');`